# WPF datagrid some times don't show data when I close and reopen window

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF datagrid in one window is acting weird some times it shows all the rows sometimes it don't.

The only trace I could find was swapping between windows, when I close or logout and then  re-open the window it doesn't work may be it doesn't refresh but I am not sure.

Following is my code behind button that populates the datagrid:

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<TextBox> textbox_list = new List<TextBox>();
            Sample_Search sample = new Sample_Search();
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.GetType() == typeof(Import_Sample))
                {
                    (window as Import_Sample).Show_Samples.ItemsSource = null;
                    (window as Import_Sample).Show_Samples.Items.Refresh();
                    (window as Import_Sample).Count_Items.Text = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Search_SMP.Children)
            {
                if (textBox.Text != null && textBox.Text != "")
                    textbox_list.Add(textBox);
            }
            if (textbox_list.Count > 0)
                sample.Search(textbox_list, "SAMPLES");
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.GetType() == typeof(Import_Sample))
                {
                    (window as Import_Sample).Count_Items.Text = "Number of Records: " + (window as Import_Sample).Show_Samples.Items.Count.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

```
public void Search(List<TextBox> textbox_list,string table_name)
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            string name = "", cond = " where ";
            for (int i = 0; i < textbox_list.Count; i++)
            {
                name = textbox_list[i].Name;
                int counter = Regex.Matches(name, "_1").Count;
                if (counter == 1)
                {
                    int index = textbox_list[i].Name.LastIndexOf(@"_");
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        name = textbox_list[i].Name.Substring(0, index);
                    }
                }
                cond += name + " Like '" + textbox_list[i].Text + "' and ";
            }
            cond = cond.Remove(cond.Length - 4);
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AU_RRM_EM].dbo." + table_name + " " + cond + "ORDER BY NUM ", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                da.Fill(table);
                for (int i = table.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (table.Columns[i].ColumnName.Contains("_"))
                    {
                        table.Columns[i].ColumnName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName.Replace("_", "__");
                    }
                    DataColumn col = table.Columns[i];
                    if (table.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.IsNull(col) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r[col].ToString())))
                        table.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            if (table_name.Contains("CONTAINERS"))
            {
                foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window.GetType() == typeof(Recipe_Linking))
                    {
                        (window as Recipe_Linking).Show_Container.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window.GetType() == typeof(Import_Sample))
                    {
                        (window as Import_Sample).Show_Samples.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Expander x:Name="Sample_Data" Header="Sample Data" IsExpanded="True" Height="450" AllowDrop="False">
     <DataGrid x:Name="Show_Samples" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable.DefaultView}"  
               AutoGenerateColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#fec758" 
               CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" 
               IsReadOnly="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ColumnWidth="*" GridLinesVisibility="All" 
               CanUserSortColumns="true" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               SelectionChanged="Show_Samples_SelectionChanged" >
                  <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                       <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                  </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
  </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If you bind the window to a view model, which instance is still alive while the `Window` is closed, the `DataGrid` would update automatically once it is loaded again. Since you seem not to use any view model as data source for your view, you must generate the data for the `DatGrid.ItemsSource` every time the `Window.Loaded` event is raised.

Comment: Also be aware that setting `DataGrid.ItemsSource` explicitly in code-behind will remove any binding that targets this property. `ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable.DefaultView`}" is without effect once overridden by an explicit assignment.